# pyinstaller importing scipy module

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, pyinstaller

A little python script that uses the scipy module executes perfectly, but when a  stand-alone executable is compiled with pyinstaller the executable fails.  Details:
Windows 10  python 2.7.10  pyinstaller 3.3.1
The error message is:

```
C:\Users\barry\Desktop\Testing>TestScipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestScipy.py", line 15, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 343, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 169, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 687, in load_module
module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[9476] Failed to execute script TestScipy
```

How can I ensure that pyinstaller loads scipy correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `scipy.stats` to the `hiddenimports` list in the .spec file and run PyInstaller again (`pyinstaller myfile.spec`). Or you could add the following option to your PyInstaller command:

```
pyinstaller [options] --hiddenimport=scipy.stats myfile.py
```

Comment: The solution proposed by apogalacticon did not work.  The executable generated exactly the same error as above.   Is it necessary to specify the path to the scipy.stats module?

Comment: Could you please trying to add scipy to the list of imports in your .py file? Something like this: `import scipy` (next line) `from scipy import stats` Does this produce the same error?

Comment: Those two lines have been in the script from the beginning.  Thanks, by the way, for your efforts to help.

Comment: It looks like the failure may be associated with line 640 of site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py . In the most recent version of scipy, this refers to numpy ufuncs. A couple of things you might want to try - update scipy and numpy (if you don't specifically need a deprecated version of these), check which module is failing to load in the site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py file (line 640 in your above error message) and make sure it is included on your system.

Comment: I updated Scipy and Numpy before my original post.  I can find nothing called unfuncs in eithre the numpy or scipy directories.  There is ufunclike.py file in numpy\lib

Answer (score 0):

The problem with pyinstaller finding scipy.stats turns out to depend on the Python installation used:
Mac OSX:  the native python in 10.13 does not exhibit the problem.
Windows 10:  Using Anaconda python eliminates the problem.
Ubuntu Linux 16.10:  Using Anaconda python eliminates the problem.